# Speed of Turtle not changing with simple Frogger style code

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

```
import time
import turtle
from turtle import Screen, Turtle
from player import Player
from car_manager import CarManager
from scoreboard import Scoreboard

screen = Screen()
screen.setup(width=600, height=600)
screen.tracer(0)

player = Player()
car_manager = CarManager()
scoreboard = Scoreboard()

screen.listen()
screen.onkey(player.go_up, "Up")


game_is_on = True
while game_is_on:
    time.sleep(0.1)
    screen.update()

    car_manager.create_car()
    car_manager.move_cars()
    for car in car_manager.all_cars:
        if car.distance(player) < 20:
            game_is_on = False
            scoreboard.game_over()

    if player.is_at_finish_line():
        player.go_to_start()
        car_manager.level_up()
        scoreboard.increase_level()


screen.exitonclick()
```

```
from turtle import Turtle
import turtle
import random


COLORS = ["red", "orange", "yellow", "green", "blue", "purple"]
STARTING_MOVE_DISTANCE = 5
MOVE_INCREMENT = 10


class CarManager:
    def __init__(self):
        self.all_cars = []
        self.car_speed = STARTING_MOVE_DISTANCE

    def create_car(self):
        random_chance = random.randint(1, 6)
        if random_chance == 1:
            new_car = Turtle("square")
            new_car.shapesize(stretch_wid=1, stretch_len=2)
            new_car.penup()
            new_car.color(random.choice(COLORS))
            random_y = random.randint(-250, 250)
            new_car.goto(300, random_y)
            self.all_cars.append(new_car)

    def move_cars(self):
        for car in self.all_cars:
            car.backward(self.car_speed)

    def level_up(self):
        self.car_speed += MOVE_INCREMENT
```

```
from turtle import Turtle
import turtle
STARTING_POSITION = (0, -280)
MOVE_DISTANCE = 10
FINISH_LINE_Y = 280

# Define Player Class


class Player(Turtle):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.shape("turtle")
        self.color("green")
        self.penup()
        self.go_to_start()
        self.setheading(90)

    def go_up(self):
        self.forward(MOVE_DISTANCE)
        self.speed(0)

    def go_to_start(self):
        self.goto(STARTING_POSITION)

    def is_at_finish_line(self):
        if self.ycor() > FINISH_LINE_Y:
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

```
from turtle import Turtle
FONT = ("Courier", 24, "normal")


class Scoreboard(Turtle):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.level = 1
        self.hideturtle()
        self.penup()
        self.goto(-270, 270)
        self.update_scoreboard()

    def update_scoreboard(self):
        self.clear()
        self.write(f"Level: {self.level}", align="left", font=FONT)

    def increase_level(self):
        self.level += 1
        self.update_scoreboard()

    def game_over(self):
        self.goto(0, 0)
        self.write(f"GAME OVER", align="center", font=FONT)
```

What I am trying to do here is modify the speed of my turtle under the class Player, in which I have defined the function go_up,

```
def go_up(self):
    self.forward(MOVE_DISTANCE)
    self.speed(0)
```

I set the go_up movement speed to 0 ("fastest"), however if I input any value here, or type out the "fastest", "slowest"... whichever value... the turtle still moves at the same rate no matter any value I input into the go_up function within the Player class.

TLDR my question is... how do I get the turtle to move faster than its current value? All values that I input seem to have the turtle at the exact same speed. Thank you.

Tried searching thru all the Python 3.11.0 documentation on turtle movement speed, tried fiddling with my code to introduce a different speed... researched here on stackoverflow. I am expecting this code to have my turtle at the "fastest" speed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I set the go_up movement speed to 0 ("fastest"), however if I input
> any value here, or type out the "fastest", "slowest"... whichever
> value... the turtle still moves at the same rate no matter any value I
> input into the go_up function

Once you invoke `tracer(0)`, the turtles' `speed()` method is a no-op.

One way you can get more performance from the player to to make it like your cars in that its increment of motion increases for each level.

Also, the `while game_is_on:` is effectively a `while True:` loop which has no place in an event-driven world like turtle.  So, let's switch to a timer event based model, along with other changes:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle
from random import randint, choice

FINISH_LINE_Y = 280

class Player(Turtle):
    PLAYER_STARTING_POSITION = (0, -280)
    PLAYER_STARTING_MOVE_DISTANCE = 10
    PLAYER_MOVE_INCREMENT = 2

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.shape('turtle')
        self.color('green')
        self.penup()
        self.go_to_start()
        self.setheading(90)
        self.player_speed = Player.PLAYER_STARTING_MOVE_DISTANCE

    def go_up(self):
        self.forward(self.player_speed)

    def go_to_start(self):
        self.goto(Player.PLAYER_STARTING_POSITION)

    def is_at_finish_line(self):
        return self.ycor() > FINISH_LINE_Y

    def level_up(self):
        self.player_speed += Player.PLAYER_MOVE_INCREMENT

class CarManager:
    CAR_STARTING_MOVE_DISTANCE = 5
    CAR_MOVE_INCREMENT = 10

    CAR_COLORS = ['red', 'orange', 'yellow', 'green', 'blue', 'purple']

    def __init__(self):
        self.all_cars = []
        self.car_speed = CarManager.CAR_STARTING_MOVE_DISTANCE

    def create_car(self):
        if randint(1, 6) == 1:
            new_car = Turtle('square')
            new_car.shapesize(stretch_wid=1, stretch_len=2)
            new_car.color(choice(CarManager.CAR_COLORS))
            new_car.penup()
            random_y = randint(-250, 250)
            new_car.goto(300, random_y)
            new_car.setheading(180)

            self.all_cars.append(new_car)

    def move_cars(self):
        for car in self.all_cars:
            car.forward(self.car_speed)

    def level_up(self):
        self.car_speed += CarManager.CAR_MOVE_INCREMENT

class Scoreboard(Turtle):
    FONT = ('Courier', 24, 'normal')

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.level = 1
        self.hideturtle()
        self.penup()
        self.goto(-270, 270)
        self.update_scoreboard()

    def update_scoreboard(self):
        self.clear()
        self.write(f"Level: {self.level}", font=Scoreboard.FONT)

    def increase_level(self):
        self.level += 1
        self.update_scoreboard()

    def game_over(self):
        self.goto(0, 0)
        self.write("GAME OVER", align='center', font=Scoreboard.FONT)

game_is_on = True

def move():
    global game_is_on

    if not game_is_on:
        return

    car_manager.create_car()
    car_manager.move_cars()

    for car in car_manager.all_cars:
        if car.distance(player) < 20:
            game_is_on = False
            scoreboard.game_over()
            break
    else:  # no break #
        if player.is_at_finish_line():
            player.go_to_start()
            player.level_up()
            car_manager.level_up()
            scoreboard.increase_level()

    screen.update()
    screen.ontimer(move, 100)

screen = Screen()
screen.setup(width=600, height=600)
screen.tracer(0)

player = Player()
car_manager = CarManager()
scoreboard = Scoreboard()

screen.onkey(player.go_up, 'Up')
screen.listen()

move()

screen.mainloop()
```

I had fun playing your (reworked) game!